# OpenCV Image color space transformation using cvtColor

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using the below opencv API to transform color space:

```
cvtColor(<input mat>, <output mat>, COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
```

However, the output image has bluishness all over the image. Is there any way to get the right image color?

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR byte ordering by default. You probably want to pass the `COLOR_BGR2BGRA` flag instead.

Comment: @Aurelius I think you should leave that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The above comment by @Aurelius is valid in other scenario.

However, my input image was already in RGB format. I was supposed to do below

```
cvtColor(<input mat>, <output mat>, COLOR_RGB2RGBA); //posted in question as well
```

instead of

```
cvtColor(<input mat>, <input mat>, COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
```

I was trying to do the color space transformation within the same cv::Mat object which it didn't like.